# Given a list of tuples, if the first element is the same, how do i add the second element inside each similar tuple

Tags: python, tuples

So if I have a list called:

```py
d = [('hey',7),('hey',7),('hello',8)]
```

how do I make it so it outputs:

```py
d = [('hey',14),('hello',8)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.groupby` and `operator.itemgetter`

```
[(k, sum(map(itemgetter(1), g))) for k, g in groupby(sorted(d), itemgetter(0))]
```

Prints:

```
[('hey', 14), ('hello', 8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [('hey', 7), ('hey', 7), ('hello', 8)]
```

Use:

```
d = {x:0 for x, y in lst}
for text, num in lst:
    d[text] = d[text] + num

new_lst = list(d.items())
print(new_lst)
```

For simple without any map or import function use:

```
s = {x[0] for x in lst}
new_lst = [(i,sum(x[1] for x in lst if x[0] == i)) for i in s]
print(new_lst)
```

or

```
s = []
for i in lst:
    if i[0] not in s:
        s.append(i[0])

new_lst = []
for i in s:
    m=[]
    for x in lst:
        if x[0] == i:
            m.append(x[1])
    tmp = (i,sum(m))
    new_lst.append(tmp)

print(new_lst)
```

Comment: I don't want it to be so complex, preferably without mapping, or any import functions

Comment: `.items()` already returns tuples, there’s no need to `map()`.

Comment: For your last method, why not use a dictionary? I don’t think using a list has any advantages, much to the contrary.